# countdown counter where the user can enter the ending date

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a countdown counter, the user can enter the Ending date in the HTML page, but the code below allows the user to enter the date only in the code. And here the counter begins by  window.onload event but i want the counter to begin when the user clicks on a button.

```
<head>
<title>JavaScript CountDown Timer</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ct = new Date(document.getElementById("endd").value);

function CountDown(initDate, id){
this.endDate = new Date(initDate);
this.countainer = document.getElementById(id);
this.numOfDays = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];
this.borrowed = 0, this.years = 0, this.months = 0, this.days = 0;
this.hours = 0, this.minutes = 0, this.seconds = 0;
this.updateNumOfDays();
this.updateCounter();
}

CountDown.prototype.updateNumOfDays=function(){
var dateNow = new Date();
var currYear = dateNow.getFullYear();
if ( (currYear % 4 == 0 && currYear % 100 != 0 ) || currYear % 400 == 0 ) {
    this.numOfDays[1] = 29;
}
var self = this;
setTimeout(function(){self.updateNumOfDays();}, (new Date((currYear+1), 1, 2) - dateNow));
}

CountDown.prototype.datePartDiff=function(then, now, MAX){
var diff = now - then - this.borrowed;
this.borrowed = 0;
if ( diff > -1 ) return diff;
this.borrowed = 1;
return (MAX + diff);
}

CountDown.prototype.calculate=function(){
var futureDate = this.endDate;
var currDate = new Date();
this.seconds = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getSeconds(),  futureDate.getSeconds(), 60);
this.minutes = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getMinutes(), futureDate.getMinutes(), 60);
this.hours = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getHours(), futureDate.getHours(), 24);
this.days = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getDate(), futureDate.getDate(), this.numOfDays[futureDate.getMonth()]);
this.months = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getMonth(), futureDate.getMonth(), 12);
this.years = this.datePartDiff(currDate.getFullYear(), futureDate.getFullYear(),0);
}

CountDown.prototype.addLeadingZero=function(value){
return value < 10 ? ("0" + value) : value;
}

CountDown.prototype.formatTime=function(){
this.seconds = this.addLeadingZero(this.seconds);
this.minutes = this.addLeadingZero(this.minutes);
this.hours = this.addLeadingZero(this.hours);
}

CountDown.prototype.updateCounter=function(){
this.calculate();
this.formatTime();
this.countainer.innerHTML ="<strong>" + this.years + "</strong> <small>" +  (this.years == 1? "year" : "years") + "</small>" +
   " <strong>" + this.months + "</strong> <small>" + (this.months == 1? "month" : "months") + "</small>" +
   " <strong>" + this.days + "</strong> <small>" + (this.days == 1? "day" : "days") + "</small>" +
   " <strong>" + this.hours + "</strong> <small>" + (this.hours == 1? "hour" : "hours") + "</small>" +
   " <strong>" + this.minutes + "</strong> <small>" + (this.minutes == 1? "minute" : "minutes") + "</small>" +
   " <strong>" + this.seconds + "</strong> <small>" + (this.seconds == 1? "second" : "seconds") + "</small>";
if ( this.endDate > (new Date()) ) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){self.updateCounter();}, 1000);
}
}
var ct= "09/30/2015";
window.onload=function(){ new CountDown( ct, 'counter'); } 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "text" id="endd">
<div id="counter">Contents of this DIV will be replaced by Count Down</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please create fiddle with your code?  What code below? You surely just need to call the function that begins the counter based on a click handler on the button

Comment: i posted the code now..

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is remove the `window.onload=function()...`, add an html button, then use Javascript to attach an [onclick listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to that button, and when the event triggers call `new Countdown(...)` like you are already doing.

jQuery tends to make this kind of thing easier but you can do it all the same in the vanilla JS you have here.

Comment: Yes i tried this but the counter does not get displayed then it simply displays     <div id="counter">Contents of this DIV will be replaced by Count Down</div>

Comment: Do you want the countdown timer to display when you click the button or do you want it to display by default and just not be started? Assuming the latter is true, then you can't have the timer triggered in the constructor -- instead you would leave the `onload` function and have the button event listener be the trigger that starts the timer itself to countdown

Comment: I want the counter to start when i click the button.